# Checking if item exists in localStorage performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Say I have a check to see if something exists in localStorage, which is faster (or is there no difference)?:

```
if (localStorage[key]) do_something();
```

or

```
if (key in localStorage) do_something;
```

I don't know what the Javscript engine does, but doesn't `localStorage[key]` return the value inside of `localStorage[key]` (assuming it is defined) even if I don't specify a variable for it? Now I know normally this would just assign a pointer to the value inside of localStorage[key], but since localStorage is a separate browser API (that may go to disk) would that change anything?

Assuming this is a relatively large string this could be slow inside performance sensitive code.

Comment: You shouldn't access localstorage in performance-critical code, because the browser is likely storing it on hard drive.

Comment: Shouldn't? What if I have to check if it is in my cache?

Comment: When the code is really performance-critical (as in executed at least 1000 times per second) you should load your whole cache from localstorage into memory.